# How do I get the max of each group?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Consider the following LINQ statement:

```
var posts = db.Posts
    .Where(p => p.Votes.Count > 0 && p.User.Confirmed)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        PostId = p.PostId,
        Votes = p.Votes.Count(),
        Hours = EntityFunctions.DiffHours(DateTime.UtcNow, p.Timestamp)
    })
    .Select(p1 => new
    {
        PostId = p1.PostId,
        Votes = p1.Votes,
        Group = p1.Hours <= 24 ? 24 :
            p1.Hours <= 168 ? 168 :
            p1.Hours <= 720 ? 720 : 0
    })
    .Where(p2 => p2.Group != 0);
```

It successfully groups a listing of posts into their respective groups: 24 hours, 168 hours, and 720 hours.

However, now I need to get the `PostId` that has the `Max` `Votes` for each group. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
var postIds = posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostId).GroupBy(x => x.Group)
                   .Select(x => x.First().PostId);
```

Or, for a bit more clarity (IMHO), and (I think) less speed:

```
var postIds = posts.GroupBy(x => x.Group).Select(g => g.Max(p => p.PostId));
```

The former has the benefit that if you want the post, and not just the `PostId`, you have that available more easily.

Comment: I see where I messed up my question. I'm sorry. I need the post with the `Max` `Votes` for each group.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at this but kind of slow.  It's a little different syntax so I'll post it anyway

```
var groups = (from p in posts
              group p by p.Group into g
              select new 
                {
                   Id = g.Max(p => p.Id),
                   Group = g.Key
                }).ToList();


var bestPosts = (from p in posts
                join j in groups on new {p.Group, p.Votes} equals new {j.Group, j.Votes}
                select p).ToList();
```

Comment: I see where I messed up my question. I'm sorry. I need the post with the Max Votes for each group.

Comment: Edited to get the posts with the best vote.  I'm thinking you could have ties though.

Answer (score 1):

Groups according to "GroupByField" and selects the max.

```
var query = from o in _context.Objects
            group o by o.GroupByField
            into group
            select new
            {
                 maxParameter = (from o in group orderby o.OrderByField select o).Last()
            };
```

and then in order to select the original (max) objects

```
var largest = query.Select(q => q.maxParameter).ToList();
```